# TensorFlow with GPU not working in JupyterHub

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, jupyterhub

I'm trying to run TensorFlow with GPU support in JupyterHub, but I'm encountering an issue. When I try to list the physical GPU devices using TensorFlow, it returns an empty list.

Here's the code and output:

[JupyterHub notebook run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EkE4.png)

But when running the same code using the same environment in the CLI, the GPU is recognised:

```
(tf) uc@nvidia-server:\~$ /home/uc/miniconda3/envs/tf/bin/python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))" 2023-08-09 10:59:51.817688: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:110\] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable \`TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0\`. 2023-08-09 10:59:51.878724: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182\] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations. To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. 2023-08-09 10:59:52.788752: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38\] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT \[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')\]
```

Here executing same environment than previous one but from notebook

[Calling bash from JupyterHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRIl8.png)

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue and get TensorFlow to recognize and use the GPU in JupyterHub?